CONSULTA CATÁLOGO API HOSPEDAJES MINISTERIO DEL INTERIOR
Tengo un problema con la consulta del catálogo del sistema de comunicación de hospedajes (WS), en la documentación que tengo da un ejemplo de xml que no funciona.
Es el mismo que saco con soapUI a partir del wsdl que me enviaron en la documentación de la versión 3.1.1. El ejemplo es el siguiente:

Cuando hago la consulta dice que no reconoce el nodo 'peticion'. Me temo que han cambiado algo en el API pero no me contestan a los correos.
Tengo la duda de si esta consulta al catálogo es una comunicación como el resto, es decir, con la cabecera y la solicitud con el xml en zip y encriptada en base64, o bien es una petición con otra estructura diferente al resto de comunicaciones del sistema de hospedajes.
¿Alguien puede pasarme un ejemplo del xml para la consulta del catálogo que le esté funcionando?
Gracias!!!

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

¿Has conseguido encontrar un ejemplo que funcione y avanzar con el resto de peticiones?
Para la consulta del catálogo simplemente usando el que genera automáticamente con los ejemplos del wsdl ya me funcionaba.
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://www.soap.servicios.hospedajes.mir.es/comunicacion">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:catalogoRequest>
         <peticion>
            <catalogo>TIPO_DOCUMENTO</catalogo>
         </peticion>
      </com:catalogoRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comprueba que tu estructura sea parecida a esta.
Sin embargo ¿has podido ejecutar una petición de comunicación? Es la única que me ha dado problemas:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:com='http://www.soap.servicios.hospedajes.mir.es/comunicacion' xmlns:ns3='http://www.soap.servicios.hospedajes.mir.es/comunicacion'>
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <com:comunicacionRequest>
            <peticion>
                <cabecera>
                    <codigoArrendador>CODIGO</codigoArrendador>
                    <aplicacion>Centro de reservas</aplicacion>
                    <tipoOperacion>A</tipoOperacion>
                    <tipoComunicacion>RH</tipoComunicacion>
                </cabecera>
                <solicitud>Aquí el comprimido</solicitud>
            </peticion>
        </com:comunicacionRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>                                 

Parece que algo no está bien explicado en la documentación sobre la compresión o el formato del mismo:

Error en el formato de fichero xml. cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the
declaration of element 'comunicacion'.

No he logrado pasar de este punto.
